# 405 angular js posting to web service (firefox)

Tags: json, web-services, wcf, angularjs, endpoint

The following code works fine using internet explorer and receives a 200 response. However, using Firefox generates a 405. When using fiddler I can see that IE passes the json object but firefox doesn't.

```
app.service('UserService', function ($http) {
    this.GetLoginStatus = function (AuthenticateRequest) {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $http({
            url: APIURL + '/Authenticate',
            method: "POST",
            options: {},
            data: AuthenticateRequest,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        });
    }; 
});
```

Fiddler inspection
FireFox
OPTIONS http://www.myapi.com:56586/V1/Service.svc/json/Authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56586
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://www.myapi.com:54567
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

IE
POST http://www.myapi.com:56586/V1/Service.svc/json/Authenticate HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://www.myapi.com:54567/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:56586
Content-Length: 45
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"UserName":"username","Password":"password"}

Comment: Is this a cross domain request? What is the exact response message in firebug?

Comment: Client and server are both running from localhost however they are on different ports. However, the final product will probably be using cross domain.

Comment: This is the error from firefox "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:56586/V1/Service.svc/json/Authenticate"

Comment: This doesn't look like a cross domain problem to me. Could you provide a plunker or jsfiddle for your problem. At first glance, what I could think of would be a cashing issue. Have you tried to clear the cache in both browsers? Or do you have a proxy set up on one of the browsers?

Comment: If you haven't already, install fiddler and watch the request being sent from both browsers.

Comment: I have fiddler install IE sends something different. I will post the info on the question.